# Enable Administrative Security on Websphere (localhost)

Tags: websphere

In the Websphere administration console under Security > Global Security, when I try to tick "Enable Administrative Security", I get the following message:

> Validation failed: SECJ7724E: Error in the user registry configuration 
>   unable to verify access to the user registry.

My WebSphere is a local installation. I cannot add any user or group while the administrative secirity is still disabled.

What/where is this user registry they are talking about? How can I enable this Administrative Security?

Answer (score 0):

Follow below link
from Global security run Security wizard

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYMRC_7.0.1/com.ibm.jazz.install.doc/topics/t_instl_config_was_registry.html

Comment: On Stack, it is preferred that you describe the solution completely within the answer so that even if the referenced link is removed that the information will remain available to someone searching the question. When you do this it is appropriate to link to the source document a a point of attribution.